# How to delete com.apple files from the Trash folder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, trash

[image]

This is the second time I'm posting this question. I hope I'm doing it right this time.

How to delete these files from trash? Any ideas? I tried several methods but I had no luck.

Methods that I tried include a number of recommendations that I saw in this forum, such as utilizing the terminal (meaning deleting the files with the help of terminal and its commands), but as I said I had no luck.

Why did I delete these files in the first place? Followed the advice of some guy in a forum. I was basically trying to solve an issue that I had with an app.

Any help and/or recommendation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than simply repost exactly the same question - which was closed as needing detail & clarity - you should edit to original to provide the requested extra information. It would also be helpful to know what macOS you are on, as that will change the answer, & why you think you need to delete these. What problem are you *actually* trying to solve? Generally, trying to manually delete anything from `/private/var/` without knowing *exactly* what you're doing is considered a **bad idea**.

Comment: Show what methods / commands you used, then we won't repeat them.

Comment: I apologize for all the inconveniences. I'm new to this forum. 

I reposted the question and deleted the initial one because I was advised to provide more details. 

I'm using the latest version of macOS, Monterey 12.2.1. I think I need to delete these as they're just sitting on my trash folder. I suppose they're not useful. I just want to fully empty my trash. 

I know this was a bad idea. I shouldn't have done this. But, I didn't know better.

I used most of the sudo commands that were recommended in this forum.

Once again, I apologize if I'm not doing things the right way.

Comment: Monterey won't let you delete things from the system volume. I'm honestly surprised it let you get this far. Sudo should not allow you to bypass Monterey's safety protocols. You may have to reinstall the OS from Recovery to clean this up. [This should not erase any personal files, but always have a backup.]

Comment: In fact, this happened a while back when I still had Big Sur. Then, I bought a new MacBook, and transferred everything to the new laptop. As much as I love the Migration Assistant feature, I hoped it won't transfer these files from trash :). But that's the beauty of it, everything stays exactly the same, it's just a new hardware. Anyway, thanks for all your help. I'll let you know if I find a solution.